# How to clear Visual Studio Code cache?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am in anaconda dependency hell so I keep building and then deleting different environments and the Visual Studio Code cache seems confused about what environments are available, for example looking for an environment that has been deleted.

I uninstalled and reinstalled VSC (Windows Server 2012 - waiting for upgrade) but the issue persists.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: are you specifically asking about python? or what do you mean by "environment"?

Answer (score 0):

When using Python in VS Code, it recognizes the available python executable file "python.exe", which we can view in the system variables:

[image]

In VS Code, it uses the python environment used last time by default, therefore, for unused python environments, you could select other available python environments in VS Code and ignore the deleted python environments. (`F1`, `Python: Select Interpreter`)

For more information about the python environment in VS Code, please refer to this document: [Using Python environments in VS Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Reference: [How do I add Python to the Windows PATH?](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path)